# In Mark 5:42 to whom did Christ give the order not to publish about the resurrected girl?

Tags: jesus, mark, gospels, christology, resurrection

After raising the little girl from the dead Christ goes on to give a charge that know one should know about this incident

Mark 5:42 NASB

> 42 Immediately the girl got up and began to walk, for she was twelve years old. And immediately they were completely astounded. 43 ***And He gave them strict orders that no one should know about this***, and He said that something should be given her to eat.

But its not clear to whom Christ gave this charge whether it was the parents,his disciples or the crowd.

To whom did did Christ give orders that no one should know about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same story is also found in Luke 8:56, and Matthew 9:25, however Luke's Gospel may provide a clue, as it says after she arose, in verse 56;

> "And her parents were astonished:  but he charged them that they should tell no man what was done."  (KJV)

This follows a similar pattern where Jesus would heal people and tell them not to spread the news that he had done the miracle.  Some examples:

1. Man healed of leprosy - Matthew 8:2-4, Mark 1:40-44, Luke 5:12-14
2. Blindness cured - Matthew 9:28-30
3. Deaf and muteness cured Mark 7:32-36
4. Blindness cured - Mark 8:22-26

Jesus told Peter, James and John not to tell what they had seen on the mountain:

Matthew 17:1-9, Mark 9:2-9, Luke 9:28-36.

So since the crowd was put out, and only Peter, James and John were permitted in, with the girls parents I would say the 'them' in Mark 5:42 is the parents and the girl, and quite possibly Peter, James and John.

Comment: While I agree with your conclusion, it is a bit hollow - the entire neighbourhood would know the girl had been resurrected and would tell everyone they knew!  All the people at the funeral would know.

Comment: @Mac'sMusings - Thank you for your comment sir.  Yes, I agree.  It doesn't seem like the news would be kept secret.  This has brought a question to mind, but as far as I'm aware, I think I need to ask an actual question, but not in the comments.

Comment: I agree. Peter, James and John from verse 37 and the father and mother from verse 40. No dispute. +1. He spoke to those who were 'astonished' KJV in the vicinity of the actual event, verse 42. What that means - is a matter of interpretation. But interpretation should not compromise the actual textual evidence.

Answer (score 0):

**In Mark 5:42 to whom did Christ give the order not to publish about the resurrected girl?**

From the parallel story of the event . Luke 8:51-56, **Jesus instructed the parents of the girl** , not to tell any one what had happened. But why?

Luke 8:51-56  (NASB)

> 51 "When He came to the house, He did not allow anyone to enter with
>   Him, except Peter and John and James, and the girl’s father and
>   mother. 52 Now they were all weeping and lamenting for her; but He
>   said, “Stop weeping, for she has not died, but is asleep.” 53 And they
>   began laughing at Him, knowing that she had died."
>
> 54 "He, however, took her by the hand and called, saying, “Child,
>   arise!” 55 And her spirit returned, and she got up immediately; and He
>   gave orders for something to be given her to eat. 56 **Her parents were
>   amazed; but He instructed them to tell no one what had happened."**

**Why did Jesus instruct them, not to tell anyone what had happened.**

His humble approach fulfilled the prophetic words of Isaiah.

Isaiah 42:1-2  (NASB)

God’s Promise concerning His Servant.

> 42 “Behold, My Servant, whom I uphold; My chosen one in whom My soul
>   delights. I have put My Spirit upon Him; He will bring forth justice
>   to the nations.  2 “He will not cry out or raise His voice, Nor make
>   His voice heard in the street.

Obviously Jesus did not want to magnify his name, or create sensational reports about his miracles, that would draw attention away from God and his  preaching of  the good news of the Kingdom of God. Further ,apparently Jesus wanted  to convince people that he was the Christ, the Messiah  himself , and not from   rumors based on his miracles.

Luke 4:43  (NRSV)

> 43" But he said to them, “I must proclaim the good news of the kingdom
>   of God to the other cities also; for I was sent for this purpose.”